# Not able to save multiple objects using nskeyedArcheiver

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use `NsKeyedArchiever` to take save Car details which contains model,make,year,color,vin.
The code for this is as follows :

```
void CarData()
{
    Car *myCar = [[Car alloc] init];
    myCar.model = [carTempArray objectAtIndex:0];//Temporary array contains value
    myCar.make = [carTempArray objectAtIndex:1];
    myCar.color = [carTempArray objectAtIndex:2];
    myCar.year = [carTempArray objectAtIndex:3];
    myCar.vin = [NSNumber numberWithInt:check];
    NSString *docspath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"documents"];
    BOOL saved =[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: myCar toFile:docspath];
    NSLog(@"did save state %d",saved);
    [myCar release];
    [NSKeyedArchiver release];
}
```

And after that using `NSkeyedUnarcheiver` as follows :

```
void ShowData()
{
    NSString *docspath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"documents"]; 

        Car * retrieveCar = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:docspath];
       // for(int i=0 ; i<studentList.count;i++)
        {
          //  Car * retrieveCar =[studentList objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString * first  = retrieveCar.model;
    NSString * first1 = retrieveCar.make;
    NSString * first2 = retrieveCar.color;
    NSString * first3 = retrieveCar.year;
    NSLog(@"%@",first );
    NSLog(@"%@",first1 );

    NSLog(@"%@",first2 );
    NSLog(@"%@",first3 );
}
```

But this only takes one value and uses one value.I want to save the `NSKeyedArchiever` object in an array so that multiple cars can be a part of it using same code.And Load the same as above.Please rectify the problem .I want to run the code for multiple cars and i am able to perform the following tasks in array of cars as searching a car,deleting a car record and adding a car.

Comment: You need to create an array to hold objects of Cars, then you need to implement NSCoding protocol. Then you can archive and write to file.

Comment: How do i use the same memory location for writing files over and over again to save a new car each time